# Lua: How to access object instance functions from another instance?

Tags: function, object, oop, lua

I want to call a Lua function of an object instance from another object instance.

But i have no clue how to, hah

the objects are instanced like this

```lua
local newPhantoon = OptionalPhantoon("OptionalPhantoon", "optionalphantoon", "images/Boss3.png")
local newObjective = ObjectiveTest("ObjectiveTest", "objectiveSwitch", "images/obj_bosses.png", "images/obj_minibosses.png", "images/obj_metroids.png", newPhantoon)
```

and these are some of the things i tried

```lua
phanTest:changePhantoon(false)
newPhantoon:OptionalPhantoon:updateIcon()
Class:CustomItem:OptionalPhantoon:updateIcon()
changePhantoon(false)
changePhantoon.ChangeVisiblity(false))
phanTest:updateIcon()
OptionalPhantoon:updateIcon()
newPhantoon:OptionalPhantoon:updateIcon()
```

whats makes this really difficult on me (other than the fact that im not that well versed on Lua) is how these classes are organized

```lua
ObjectiveTest = CustomItem:extend()--from file 3
CustomItem = class()--from file 2

function Class:extend(obj)--from file 1
    local obj = obj or {}

    local function copyTable(table, destination)
        local table = table or {}
        local result = destination or {}

        for k, v in pairs(table) do
            if not result[k] then
                if type(v) == "table" and k ~= "__index" and k ~= "__newindex" then
                    result[k] = copyTable(v)
                else
                    result[k] = v
                end
            end
        end

        return result
    end

    copyTable(self, obj)

    obj._ = obj._ or {}

    local mt = {}

    -- create new objects directly, like o = Object()
    mt.__call = function(self, ...)
        return self:new(...)
    end

    -- allow for getters and setters
    mt.__index = function(table, key)
        local val = rawget(table._, key)
        if val and type(val) == "table" and (val.get ~= nil or val.value ~= nil) then
            if val.get then
                if type(val.get) == "function" then
                    return val.get(table, val.value)
                else
                    return val.get
                end
            elseif val.value then
                return val.value
            end
        else
            return val
        end
    end

    mt.__newindex = function(table, key, value)
        local val = rawget(table._, key)
        if val and type(val) == "table" and ((val.set ~= nil and val._ == nil) or val.value ~= nil) then
            local v = value
            if val.set then
                if type(val.set) == "function" then
                    v = val.set(table, value, val.value)
                else
                    v = val.set
                end
            end
            val.value = v
            if val and val.afterSet then val.afterSet(table, v) end
        else
            table._[key] = value
        end
    end

    setmetatable(obj, mt)

    return obj
end
```

just in case this helps, ive been trying to figure out EmoTracker and its SDK